# Windows 10 IoT Universal App Deployment Fails on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Problem with debugging on Raspberry Pi 2.
I have a simple Universal app (for testing purposes only "hello world", it's not the code that causes trouble).

I want to debug this app on my raspberry pi 2.
Yesterday, it all worked perfectly, but now, it's always starting to deploy, and then fails.

The Configuration of the Pi is all okay (Remote, ARM, No authentification..).
I installed the update (I'm using Windows 10) KB3081424, which I already uninstalled again, without any changes.

Also I checked the folders "AppReadiness" and "AUInstallAgent" on C:\Windows, which also exists...

Edit: I get the Error "Build Action 'Embedded Ressource' are not supported by Projects with output-type 'appcontainerexe'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you are receiving "Build Action 'Embedded Ressource'".  You may want to ensure that you do not have any items in your Solution Explorer set to a Build Action of Embedded Resource.  You can check this in the Solution Explorer as indicated below:

[image]